# Application cancelling shutdown

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I'm having a problem with an application that seems to cancel the shutdown or restart of my computer.
I think it's because I capture the form closing event and cancel it like this:

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!AllowApplicationClose)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```

I do this so that the close button just minimizes to the task bar. I do want to be able to restart without exiting the application though. Is there a better way to do this? Or a way to know if windows is closing the application?

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. Sorry I could only pick one as correct, I just went with the top one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CloseReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx) to detect if the form is being closed by the user or better (in your case) use the [`SystemEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx)-class to get an event when the system is trying to log off or shutdown/restart so you can also close the application when it is minimized.

Answer (score 2):

Check [`e.CloseReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx) first; only cancel if it's user initiated: `CloseReason.UserClosing`.

See here for other values you could use: [CloseReason (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`CloseReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx) of the event arguments and do nothing if it is either `WindowsShutDown` or `TaskManagerClosing`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a threaded timer procedure then the below procedure to shut windows processes respectively.

```
public void Computer_Shutdown()
        {
            if (this.checkBox.Checked)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes = 
                   System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();

                foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process 
                           processParent in processes)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process[] processNames = 
                                 System.Diagnostics.Process.
                                 GetProcessesByName
                                 (processParent.ProcessName);

                    foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process 
                            processChild in processNames)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            System.IntPtr hWnd = 
                                   processChild.MainWindowHandle;

                            if (IsIconic(hWnd))
                            {
                                ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
                            }

                            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

                            if (!(processChild.
                               MainWindowTitle.Equals(this.Text)))
                            {
                                processChild.CloseMainWindow();
                                processChild.Kill();
                                processChild.WaitForExit();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception exception)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: That will end processes, I don't think this is what the original poster (OP) wants to do. he's interested in not cancelling his app closing when windows shuts down.